# Handling special charaters æ,ø,å in objective c - iphone

Tags: iphone, utf-8, nsstring

I have a UILabel which I change through the code. However when I create a NSString with the charaters æ,ø,å(Danish) I get an input conversion warning. The code look as this:

```
NSString *label=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"Prøv igen"];
```

And the warning I get is this - warning: input conversion stopped due to an input byte that does not belong to the input codeset UTF-8. I can understand that ø is probably not an UTF encoding but what to do? Anyone who can give me a hint about what to do to solves this?

Regards

Bjarke

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your source code is not saved as UTF-8, but most likely as something like ISO-8859-1.

Just open the file and re-save it as UTF-8 - and while you're at it, you should probably also make that the default. Exactly how to do that depends on what editor you're using.

Comment: Hey thank you for the answer, Iam using Xcode - I will give it a try right away

Comment: I went to preferences under xcode and set it to UTF8 as default when saving files. However it did not remove the warning.

Comment: @user597218: Just setting the default won't change your current files - those get detected as whatever character set they already used, and then the editor will keep using that unless told otherwise. You have to open the file, tell XCode to use UTF-8 *for that file*, and save it. I don't have a Mac, so I can't tell you where in XCode you might do that, but I would assume it's an option or menu item somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your file text encoding is set to UTF-8, not Western (ISO) or something else. You can use the Xcode file info inspector to do this.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeWorkspace/050-File_Management/file_management.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002677-BABICEHI

Make sure it says Unicode (UTF-8) for the File Encoding. If it asks you, tell it to reinterpret your file with the new encoding. Also, you may want to delete the problematic text and reinput it to get it to work.

Comment: I went to preferences under xcode and set it to UTF8 as default when saving files or is this not what you mean with inspector?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but my source code files were already UTF-8 encoded so I fix it in a different way.
In your case, it would have been something like

> NSString *label=[NSString stringWithUTF8String"Prøv igen"];

I hope this will be helpful for others who stumble on this question